# Eclipse overwrite file on build without confirmation?

Tags: java, eclipse

I compile pretty often and the file-overwrite confirmation when building in Eclipse keeps bothering me.
Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: A few days ago I asked something similar to this, which might be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349519/eclipse-how-to-prevent-it-from-cleaning-the-bin-folder-every-build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Window - Preferances- Text Editors

In Text Editors one check box  **Disable overwrite typing mode**  is there .

Uncheck  it , this might bothering you.

Comment: that option doesn't exist in my version of Eclipse. It is Titanium Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Neither it exists in Indigo.
Some have suggested to uncheck "Warn before editing a derived file" without success either.
I noticed that it started right after I upgraded OpenAFS to 1.7.4 so it maybe some problem related to the AFS tokens.
Someone else suggested that time synchronization could cause it - which makes sense if the AFS tokens are the problem... so I set my laptop clock with the AFS server clock but no luck so far... Still investigating...