# Bash script getting deleted automatically on OS X git repository inside Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, git, bash, zsh

I have a bash script that I use to simply **change directory, compile, change the directory back, and run my code**.

The root project is a git repository; however, the directory **`bin`**, which contains my bash script is excluded in `.gitignore`.

I am on OS X in zsh, and using Eclipse for editing the project.

**Every now and then, the bash script automatically gets deleted!!**

I am not able to associate it with any particular event. It's just that after executing a certain number of times, it simply disappears.

I am not sure whether this is caused due to Eclipse or git or something else. What could be the problem?

**N.B:** I am sure no one else is accessing my system.

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: It was inherent; now it has been made explicit.

Comment: Check if there are any git hooks configured that could be the cause. That or something like a Makefile

Comment: Just a hunch: Eclipse uses `bin` for storing compiled classes, libraries etc. Maybe this happens when you hit "Clean Project"?

Comment: No. I haven't cleaned my project ever. I am using eclipse only for editing the code. However, I have 'rm *.class' inside the same bash script as the first statement..

Comment: I noticed that this usually (not always, though) happens when I save some file from Eclipse. After I switch back to the terminal, the script disappears!
_p.s._: I use vrapper in Eclipse.

Comment: Don't use the `bin` folder. Store your script in some other location, since Eclipse [empties the bin folder for every build](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6349613/201318). I use folders named `dist`, `scripts` or similar for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @kba. Moving the script to `src` folder worked.